# Stop post being published

Tags: callbacks

i am attempting to stop a page from being published if certain criteria are not met using the `transition_post_status` hook.  However the `WP_DIE` does not stop the post from being published.

```
function check_post_limit( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

      if($new_status == 'publish'){

          wp_die();
      }
 }

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'check_post_limit', 10, 3 );
```

`

Answer (score 1):

`wp_die();` will run AFTER the post is published. You are checking whether the post is published or not, which means the post is already published, what's done is done. You can update to post status from published to draft instead of using `wp_die();`. The following code will do it:

```
function check_post_limit( $ID, $post ) {
          $post = array( 'ID' => $ID, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
          wp_update_post($post);
 }
add_action( 'publish_post', 'check_post_limit', 10, 2 );
```